# listview cursor get item on itemclick

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a listview with some elements that are saved on a database and I access them using a custom content provider.

In my main activity, I have implemented a ResourceCursorAdapter.

What I need is, when I click on a element of the list, the cursor have to access to this item's parameters and send them to another activity. I have almost this done, but I think I'm not getting right the cursor's position. The true is that I don't know how to do this, if I have to use the ID to access the item on the database, or using the position is enough.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TravelActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_CITY, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_YEAR, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_NOTE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE)));

        cursor.close();

        startActivity(intent);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor cursor = ((CursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TravelActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_CITY, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_YEAR, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR)));
        intent.putExtra(TravelActivity.EXTRA_NOTE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE)));

        startActivity(intent);
        cursor.close();           
    }
}
```

Also, this is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getTravelsAdapter();

    //...
}

public void getTravelsAdapter() {

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    mAdapter = new TravelsCursorAdapter(this, c);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: this `while(cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {` plus `cursor.close();` in the loop a/ makes no sense b/ most likely crashes

Comment: why don't you use the id in your query ?

Comment: @njzk2 do you propose to delete the while loop? I'm new with this and I don't know how to implement this methods, so I listen for any proposals

Comment: your update should work, yes.

Comment: the cursor.close is probably not necessary, though.

Comment: @njzk2, works only one time. If I return to the list an click on another item, the app closes

Comment: possibly because of the closing of the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to get the adapter through

```
l.getAdapter()
```

and safely cast the returned value to your implementation of `ResourceCursorAdapter`. Than you can use `getCursor` on the returned value of the previous call, and get the cursor.
Once you get the cursor you can move to position with `Cursor.moveToPosition(position);` and retrieve your data

Example:

```
Cursor cursor = ((TravelsCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

Comment: COuld you extend a bit more detailed explanation? I'm starting with all this SQL, ContentProviders, Cursors stuff and still is a bit messy for me... I'm trying to read a lot to learn, but still I don't understand some concepts

Comment: Does not let me use (myCursorAdapter) to cast there. I'm able to do it writing there (cursor) or (cursorAdapter)

Comment: could you update your question with the new snippet?

Comment: when I click on a list item, it should start other activity where it shows just the parameters (city, country, year, note) of the selected item. When i do this, the app freezes, so I don't know what is the problem there

Comment: could you post the stacktrace (If you got a crash)

Comment: Mmm, do you mean the LogCat? Now works, but only one time. If I go back to the list and click on another item, then the app closes.

Comment: that's another issue. Try to track back your problem and if you are not able to resolve it post another question